# Watson assistant visit url or preview link is not working in IE

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Watson assistant visit url or preview link is not working in IE browser but the same link is working in Chrome browser.
Is there a limitation on IE version?

I am using IE11 version

Comment: Can you please provide the URL or the place where you are getting the URL?

Comment: @MamoonRaja, below is the link, please check.
https://assistant-chat-eu-gb.watsonplatform.net/web/public/ca82413d-dda2-43b5-8f61-88747787b37a

Comment: any idea why its not working in IE ?